# Unable to run object detection code on Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, faster-rcnn

I wanted to run the demo.py with a pre-trained model (mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml) that was completed in Colab and saved somewhere as .pth

So when I run the below in colab with demo

```
!python demo.py --config-file /content/detectron2/configs/COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x.yaml --input [DIR INPUT] --output [DIR OUTPUT] --confidence-threshold 0.7 --opts MODEL.WEIGHTS [DIR PATH].pth
```

I get an image output to the DIR OUTPUT, however, it is not detecting what I had trained the model on in Colab and I get the below warnings

```
WARNING [08/23 15:10:22 fvcore.common.checkpoint]: Skip loading parameter 'backbone.bottom_up.res2.0.conv1.weight' to the model due to incompatible shapes: (256, 64, 1, 1) in the checkpoint but (64, 64, 1, 1) in the model! You might want to double check if this is expected.
WARNING [08/23 15:10:22 fvcore.common.checkpoint]: Skip loading parameter 'backbone.bottom_up.res2.0.conv1.norm.weight' to the model due to incompatible shapes: (256,) in the checkpoint but (64,) in the model! You might want to double check if this is expected.
WARNING [08/23 15:10:22 fvcore.common.checkpoint]: Skip loading parameter 'backbone.bottom_up.res2.0.conv1.norm.bias' to the model due to incompatible shapes: (256,) in the checkpoint but (64,) in the model! You might want to double check if this is expected.
WARNING [08/23 15:10:22 fvcore.common.checkpoint]: Skip loading parameter 'backbone.bottom_up.res2.0.conv1.norm.running_mean' to the model due to incompatible shapes: (256,) in the checkpoint but (64,) in the model! You might want to double check if this is expected.
```

It seems that The config that's used to train the model is needed, but I am not sure what else needs to be added to that command line. Sorry, I am very new to detectron2 and I am learning by doing.

Please support

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: @NewNerd, I have updated your question with an appropriate title, and some formatting. Please read [ask] and ensure you are asking your question in the suggested method so that SO users can assist you better. Please edit your question further accordingly as it may be flagged for "low quality" and subsequently removed.